# how to override wordpress parent theme theme options in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, child-theming

I want to override the parent theme option in child theme, so how can I do this in using code inside my child theme.
My problem is this,
I have use the ready-made word-press theme now, I want the some new options in theme options using my child theme so is there any way to override theme options.
I have also include my theme optional file like below:

```
include (CHILD_DIR.'admin/theme-options-dependency.php');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of let me know which theme you have used. In theme you don't need to override theme option just check parent theme option code you have find lots of action and filter when theme option register. You just use that filter & action and add your extra option with filter.

Comment: i am using Highend Ultimate Multi-Purpose WordPress Theme, 
and have did some customization in this theme, so when i update the theme my code will loss.
to solve this, i've created child theme for overriding my customization.